# Leiningen: How to include specific dependencies in jar?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am attempting to create a jar which contains just a part of the dependencies. I read about uberjar but that contains all dependencies but I would like to point out the exact dependencies I would like to include in the final jar

Comment: Have you tried moving the unwanted libs into another profile (e.g. dev)?

Comment: @cfrick thanks that solved it. It still adds the clojure library inside, but not any company specific dependencies. Thanks. Don't know how to make a comment the answer of the question.

Comment: If you only want yo have your files, don't build an uberjar at all.  Build the regular artifact - it contains only the local code - no deps what so ever.  But of course you would have to provide at least the clojure/spec/.. jars separately to make it run.